# Avoid altering user arguments by deepcopy in the __init__ method?

Tags: python

I want to avoid that user arguments get changed after creating a new instance of an object and working with the object. Is it good practice here to immediately copy the critical arguments in the **init**() method or is there a better solution?

Here is a specific example:

```
import copy
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = copy.deepcopy(x)

    def change(self):
        self.x[0] += 1


>>> x = [0]
>>> C = Myclass(x)
>>> C.change()
>>> print(x)
0
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: It's not a matter of practice. If you need to copy, then you need to copy. There's nothing more to that.

Comment: My opinion is that the copying should _usually_ be the responsibility of the caller.  This introduces overhead in the (likely) common case where the user doesn't care if the contents of the input are changed which can be avoided by just pushing that responsibility back on the caller.  With that said, practicality does sometimes beat purity and if you want to do this for practical reasons, there probably isn't a better way than what you're suggesting here.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist This is Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of Fluent Python - Luciano Ramalho - has examples in his book of coping in the `__init__.py` and I'd be incline to aggree with him.

He doesn't use deep copy however, he just takes advantage that you can initialise a list with another. Saves you an `import`.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options: list):
        self.options = list(options)
```

Great book; Highly recommended.

Comment: `list(options)` is basically the same as `copy.copy(options)` (both are shallow copies). With `x = [object()]`, compare `x` to `list(x)`, `copy.copy(x)`, and `copy.deepcopy(x)`.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't consider nested objects. I was going from the given example using an Int